# no more free space after android update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, updates, internal-storage

I have a Samsung J5 since I upgraded to android 6.0.1, I lost 4.61 GB from my storage space, its 8GB in total. I tried to wipe data and still 4.61 GB is used. I do not know how to delete the files or to return to an old android version but I really need those 4.61 GB

Help please

Answer (score 0):

No way to revert back to an old version since you are on marshmallow, Samsung won't allow you to, for security reasons.

You can get back some space by uninstalling​  bloatwares, but you'll need root.

Try also moving movable apps to an external memory, works with mine (I also have a J5 8GB), at *`Settings > Application​ > Application Manager`*